# Desenvolvimento de apps para Android: quais as ferramentas e linguagem para iniciar um projeto?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de me aventurar na criação de aplicativos para Android. A princípio faria um apenas para uso próprio.

Quais as ferramentas que eu precisaria para montar o meu ambiente de desenvolvimento? Minha aplicação usaria banco de dados, existe algum mais recomendado?

E a linguagem, há opções ou é somente java?

Comment: O padrão é Java, mas sei que é possível programar em C# e Delphi (não sei com quais limitações). Dê uma pesquisada.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta alternativa: http://xamarin.com/ (não tenho nenhuma afiliação com a empresa, nem sequer uso o produto). Para algumas pessoas pode ser uma alternativa melhor.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info

Comment: Atualizando, além do Java é possível também programar em Kotlin.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Ferramentas necessárias para o início do desenvolvimento

1. [SDK do Android](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
2. Uma IDE: [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) ou [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (descontinuado)

[Aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/iniciando-o-desenvolvimento-com-android/21025), tem um tutorial ensinando você a configurar tudo certinho.

Tem uma apostila android, que eu recomendo, é essa [aqui](http://www.k19.com.br/downloads/apostilas/java/k19-k41-desenvolvimento-mobile-com-android)

## Opções de linguagem:

Pra programar pra android, o ideal é em Java ou Kotlin, que são as duas linguagens oficiais do Android (podendo inclusive ser combinadas, isto é, algumas classes em Kotlin e outras em Java), mas também tem outras opções como o [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), que é um framework que permite programar utilizando **HTML5** e **Javascript**

Tutoriais de como usar o [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), [aqui](http://www.tekzoom.com.br/phonegap-crie-apps-para-iphone-e-android-utilizando-html5-e-css/) e [aqui](http://www.loiane.com/2012/06/comecando-com-phone-gap-cordova-hello-world-android/)

## Persistência de dados

A API do Android oferece diferentes opções quando se trata de salvar dados para serem usados
posteriormente. Qual a opção é mais apropriada depende do tipo de informação que será salva e da
disponibilidade que você quer que ela tenha.
**Segue alguns:**

1. Shared Preferences
2. SQLite
3. Internal Storage
4. External Storage
5. Armazenamento em Cache

Comment: Em termos de banco de dados é SQLite mesmo. Assim como o Java, o SQLite já vem com o Android.

Comment: Apenas por curiosidade, por que você recomenda o Eclipse? Acredito que o Android Studio seja mais fluido e mais simples de configurar.

Comment: @TobyMosque A Google fez o lançamento da versão 1.0 do Android Studio no final do ano passado. Sendo assim, quando foi feita essa resposta, acredito que não era muito estável.

Comment: Não notei que a pergunta era antiga, alguém deve ter desenterrado esta questão fazendo ela ir para topo do meu feed

Answer (score 4):

Existem várias IDE para o desenvolvimento Android.
Eu utilizo o Eclipse com plugin para Android, abaixo algumas que conheço:

- Xamarin Studio
- Visual Studio
- Eclipse
- Android Studio

O Monodroid é hoje uma das melhores opções para quem quer desenvolver para Android sem abandonar o Visual Studio. Para quem conhece Visual Studio e C#, isto é muito valioso.

Em relação ao banco de dados o Android utiliza como nativo o SQLite.

Answer (score 3):

Para desenvolver para android você tem duas opções ou usa `WebApp` ou nativo.

1. WebApp
   Você vai usar de conhecimento de `Html5`+`CSS3`+`Javascript` e depois vai empacotar essa tua app com opções como [phonegap/cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) [titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/) ou outra, a aplicação vai ser web, mas vai rodar "nativo" vai ser mais lenta que uma aplicação nativa mas com poucas alterações roda em android e iOS.
   Essas ferramentas que empacotam o teu código tem bibliotecas(em javascript) que te possibilitam acesso ao teu device e então tu consegue quase tudo aquilo que tu conseguiria com uma aplicação nativa.
2. Aplicação Nativa
   Você vai ter as vantagens de performance e mais opções de acesso as configurações do celular basicamente.
   Vai precisar de Android SDK, [aqui](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?utm_source=weibolife), e é recomendável usar o eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

A ferramenta padrão para desenvolvimento para Android é o *Android SDK*, você pode conferir no [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?utm_source=weibolife).

O sistema operacional como um todo foi pensado para rodar aplicações Java e por isso é um pouco difícil fugir dele. Existe a possibilidade de executar código nativo, em linguagem C, porém isso é pouco recomendado pela Google. Mesmo assim você não desenvolveria aplicações para usuário final sem utilizar Java, mas em geral apenas bibliotecas.

Sobre necessidade de banco de dados, para base local você provavelmente quer utilizar SQLite. Senão provavelmente utilizará alguma tecnologia de web service.

Existe uma versão do IDE Eclipse que integra o Android SDK onde você consegue pré-visualizar o seu trabalho, o que faz o trabalho ser, pelo menos em relação ao desenvolvimento de interface com o usuário, mais produtivo.

Answer (score 2):

Uma ferramenta para desenvolver em uma única linguagem mas gerando para varias plataformas em forma Nativa (Android, iOS) é o GeneXus: 
http://www.genexus.com/SD/desenvolvimento-aplicativos-moveis?pt

Permite não somente criar o app Smart Device em forma nativa, mas também o backend web (Java, C#, Ruby) para o App se conectar e sincronizar os dados de forma automática com qualquer banco de dados (Mysql, Oracle, MSSQL, Postgresql, Db2).

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção para desenvolvimento tanto pra Android, iOS e outros é o [Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/titanium-studio/).

Trabalha com estrutura MVC, a maioria do seu código é em javascript e de fácil entendimento.

Comment: Essencial para desenvolvimento ágil, porém não aproveita o máximo que o S.O. pode oferecer.